# Speed of Tampura app during Bansuri practice

Tags: flute, woodwinds, indian-classical, bansuri

I understand Tampura app (I use Tampura droid) must be on during Bansuri practice so player learns to tell (by ear) whether they are in tune.

Since I have A-Scale Bansuri the Tampura is on A-Scale and note PA (from Sa RecGa Ma PA DHA NI SA)

But what 'speed' to keep it. By default the slider is in the middle. When do I speed up the Tampura? When do I slow down the Tampura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to you to use which speed to use. I prefer it a bit slow (slider at about 1/4th position) so that I can hear all the four notes separately. Also before start practicing just keep listening to the tanpur will help you get adjust to it